# Rails 6 and active admin translate enum field in show and index pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Rails 6.0.3, activeadmin 2.8.1.
In model I am usign enum for `status` attribute:

`enum status: { draft: 0, created: 10, approved: 20, notified: 30, cancelled: 40 }`

This the locale:

```
#config/locales/it.yml  
it:
  activerecord:
    models:
      fine:
        one: verbale
        other: verbali
    attributes:
      fine:
        statuses:
          draft: bozza
          created: creato
          approved: approvato
          notified: notificato
          cancelled: cancellato
```

In Activeadmin in the show and in the index page the fine's status is not translated.

`http://localhost:3000/admin/fines/30`

`http://localhost:3000/admin/fines`

In the edit page the status select box **is translated**. After editing the show page is shown but the enum field is not translated.

What is the best way to translate an enum field in ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use decorators to do this. I tried `draper` gem and the following worked for me:

```rb
# app/decorators/fine_decorator.rb

class FineDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def status
    I18n.translate(super, scope: 'activerecord.attributes.fine.statuses')
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/admin/fines.rb

ActiveAdmin.register Fine do
  decorate_with FineDecorator
  ...
end
```

If you want to have more generic solution, you can introduce `translate_attribute` helper in the base application decorator:

```rb
# app/decorators/application_decorator.rb
class ApplicationDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def self.translate_attribute(attribute)
    define_method attribute do
      I18n.translate(
        super(),
        scope: [
          self.class.object_class.i18n_scope,
          :attributes,
          self.class.object_class.model_name.i18n_key,
          attribute.to_s.pluralize
        ]
      )
    end
  end
end

# app/decorators/fine_decorator.rb
class FineDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  translate_attribute :status
  translate_attribute :other_enum_field
end
```

This all can be achieved without using the `draper` gem, but it requires a bit more tweaking of the decorator classes.